# What to do with pre-compiled Linux binary of Julia?

Tags: ubuntu, julia

Unfortunately, the PPA in Ubuntu lags behind the latest stable release of Julia, which I need. (I do not want nightly builds.)

I downloaded the Linux binary from here:
http://julialang.org/downloads/

Now, where do I put the binary so that when I type `julia` in the terminal, it uses this new stable release instead of the old one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at what

```
echo $PATH
```

contains and place it 'earlier' than `/usr/bin`.  Both `/usr/local/bin` and (if you have it) `~/bin/` are common choices.

If you don't yet have `~/bin/` then do

```
mkdir ~/bin
edit ~/.profile   # set PATH via, say,  PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Ah thanks, I found `/usr/bin/julia`. I moved the binary to `/usr/bin/` as `julia2` so I don't overwrite `julia`.

I get an error when I run it now:

`julia2: error while loading shared libraries: libjulia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Don't do those things. That is not what I suggested.

Comment: Ah I see.

So the way Ubuntu works when I type in 'program_x' in the termal is to search for binaries in the folders listed in the environment variable `$PATH`, in order. By adding where this binary is to my `$PATH` variable, Ubuntu finds this Julia binary before the old one.

Comment: Yes, that is pretty much it.  You can simply shadow the originals that way.  Don't rename or remove files the package management system installed unless you **really** now what you are doing.